# WPF MVVMLight Messenger UI thread issue

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have an issue regarding using MVVMLight messenger in a WPF (MVVM) application. In a view I have an element (**LoadingControl**) which visibility property is bound to a viewmodel property (***IsBusy***) by using custom visibility converter. In a viewmodel I change the property value (***IsBusy***) by sending a MVVM message:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new LoadingMessage(true));
```

Here I have the method in a viewmodel which is resgistered to accept **LoadingMessage** messages, where ***IsBusy*** property is changed.

This works fine, however in one of my viewmodel methods where I send this message, UI thread blocks and ***IsBusy*** property value changes, but visibility of my UI element **LoadingControl** doesn't until main operation is not finished, e.g.:

```
void Call() {
    Messenger.Default.Send(new LoadingMessage(true));

    SomeServiceCall();
    Navigate(); // <- this works with UI, too
} // <- this is the place when LoadingControl is shown.
```

I guess that the problem is because in a viewmodel the execution is not on the ui thread, so I tried to call this directly in a **Call()** method:

```
DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
{
    IsBusy = true;
});
```

But this doesn't work too, **LoadingControl** is not shown until method ends. As I'm not so familiar with multithreading, I supose that there is some other issue here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another (lighter) way can be to fire and forget your code with Task

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
   { 
       Messenger.Default.Send(new LoadingMessage(true));
       SomeServiceCall();
       Navigate();
   });
```

If you want to force your `Action` to be executed on another thread, you can pass `TaskScheduler.Default` to the [`StartNew()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd781658%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call. But by doing so, you might fall on `Invalid cross-thread access Exception`, since you code no longer executes on the UI thread, but on a Background one. So you might need to Dispatch your code setting view-bounded properties (like your `IsBusy`) back to the UI-Thread by using the `Dispatcher` :

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    IsBusy = true;
}
```

Comment: This shows a control, but in the end I get this: 

    An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in      PresentationCore.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer just before your comment about this :)

Comment: I changed to the latest solution, but now its not working (control is not shown). This is my HandleLoadingMessage() now:

    void HandleLoadingMessage(LoadingMessage msg)
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                IsBusy = msg.IsLoading;
            }));
}

Comment: You have to first pass the IsBusy to true on the UI thread. Then make your background service call with `Task.Factory.StartNew`, and then only manage UI-bounded properties with `Dispatcher`. Maybe your loading is too fast to show your busy control. You can put a breakpoint in your VisibilityConverter to see if there's a PropertyChanged.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understands. I tried like in the example above, and it doesn't show my control. When I move Messenger.Default.Send(new LoadingMessage(true)); before of Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ..., then it shows but on the end (navigation) I get the error like I decribed in the first comment.

Comment: When you have a cross thread exception on a line, it's because you assign a value from a background thread. So you have to dispatch your assignment code on the UI Thread. To do that, in order to assign the value from the UI Thread, you have to Dispatch your code : it means you have to encapsulate the line over which the Exception happens within a call to either `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` or `DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI()` (which is MvvmLight equivalent Dispatcher)

Comment: O.K. I did this already. Every time I set IsBusy in this way: 

Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    IsBusy = msg.IsLoading;
}

Comment: Put a break-point in the converter you bound to the IsBusy property. If you hit the break-point, then your problem is with your control, or with the way you have plug it into your app. If you don't hit your break-point, then your problem is the IsBusy assignation are not called. Also, make sure that PropertyChanged() is called inside IsBusy...

Comment: I found where is the problem. When app start,     Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                IsBusy = msg.IsLoading;
            }));

is invoked and set IsBusy on false; Later, when I call  Messenger.Default.Send(new LoadingMessage(true));, like in your example, the code above which set IsBusy is skipped ?

Comment: I succeded but in this way, Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
   { 
       Messenger.Default.Send(new LoadingMessage(true));
       SomeServiceCall();
         Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Messenger.Default.Send(new LoadingMessage(false));
                   Navigate();
                }));
   });

However, in my HandleLoadingMessage I just set:  IsBusy = msg.IsLoading;. This works, but is this correct ?

Comment: Since you use Messenger.Send, there is somewhere else in your code something attached with Messenger.Register ? I think you should better have encapsulated just the IsBusy = ... on the Messenger.Register side, because there are no reason to execute the messenger code on the UI thread. In the same logic, the Navigate() function have IsBusy = ... inside of it. So it should be cleaner to just encapsulate this IsBusy assignment inside the Navigate() function, than the whole Navigate() function

Comment: Yes, as I said, I have registered this message in a viewmodel constructor with method HandleLoadingMessage in which I set IsBusy = msg.IsLoading;

Answer (score 2):

Messenger sends message in your thread so you need to wait. I think you need to send message in another thread.

```
DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
{
    Messenger.Default.Send(new LoadingMessage(true));
});
```

Comment: You might want to provide a bit more background on your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer